# Does updating across horizontal partitions hurt performance (MySql)?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table with four columns and an ever increasing amount of rows (lets say a couple million). It's the biggest table I have to deal with. I do batch insert, update, and deletes on it often. The rows included in these will have no rhyme or reason. I also select on it often but every time I select I select rows in small groups based on a certain column. So for instance I select all rows where ColumnA = x and that might average out to 10 or so rows per select.

I figure horizontal partitioning could speed up selects so I don't have to search the whole table every time but Im wondering if there will be a potentially big performance penalty on my batch inserts, updates, and deletes? There will be no simple way to prevent them from spanning multiple, if not all, partitions.

Comment: Do you have an index on `columnA`?  That would be the logical thing to do for your query.

Comment: @Gordon Yep I have an index on the column. I was thinking of using partitions as well for increased performance

Comment: If you have an index, then you are not "search[ing] the whole table every time".